# Asynchronous return of an XML feed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to perform an Asynchronous return of data in an external XML page using LINQ to XML, to then perfrom a for each loop on (I'm looking to create a new page for each item, so foreach item in myData, new page, new button, new label ect)

I was wondering whats the best type to get the data into to make it easy to perform the foreach loop, and how to do this?

Heres a sample of my XML. I'm aware in my LINQ to XML i need to use namespaces, and know how to get these.

```
<category term="theoryDatabaseModel.questionTable" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Id>1</d:Id>
    <d:Text>This is sample XML Text</d:Text>
    <d:ImageURL m:null="true" />
    <d:CategoryId>3</d:CategoryId>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

I've been using the following code to get items locally into a list, but now need to do it asynchronously.

```
List<CategoryFeedItem> catfeedItems = (from categories in docu.Descendants(mm + "properties")
                                            select new CategoryFeedItem()

                                         {
                                             CategoryId = categories.Descendants().ToList()[0].Value,
                                             CategoryText = categories.Descendants().ToList()[1].Value,

                                         }).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** 
I've used this which works, and brings me back the list in a list box.
Could i parse this data with forEach somehow to break it down into item by item?
I'll have a look into BackgroundWorker too, thanks for that.

```
public class CategoryFeedItem
{

    public string CategoryId { set; get; }
    public string CategoryText { set; get; }
```

}

```
public class CategoryFeed
{

    ListBox myCatContext;

    public void LoadCatFeed(ListBox context)
    {
        myCatContext = context;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://mydatasource.svc"));
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);
    }

    private static readonly XNamespace mm = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {


        HttpWebRequest request =
          (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response =
          (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        XDocument docu = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

        List<CategoryFeedItem> catfeedItems = (from categories in docu.Descendants(mm + "properties")
                                            select new CategoryFeedItem()

                                         {
                                             CategoryId = categories.Descendants().ToList()[0].Value,
                                             CategoryText = categories.Descendants().ToList()[1].Value,
                                         }).ToList();

        myCatContext.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { myCatContext.ItemsSource = catfeedItems; });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve. Do you just want to run this whole process (of populating the list) asynchronously or do you want notification as each item is added?

Comment: The whole process, it doesn't require notification of each item.
I just need to get the list so I can start querying it, if a list is the best way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do the loading in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this, i've written something similar but might see what BackgroundWorker can do

Comment: @beat145 as per your updated question. If you're populating your list in the HttpWebRequest callback then it's already running asynchronously. You may want to call `LoadCatFeed` in a BackgroundWorker or a blocking UI would stop it processing the response.